# verify attribute is not present in DOM after an action - Protractor

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox, dynamic, protractor

I have a dynamic attribute, which disappears once certain action is performed on it:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="includeUnclaimedChk">
```

For example, once this checkbox is unchecked, then `checked="checked"` completely disappears from DOM. How can I verify this in Protractor?

What I have done currently is to verify this attribute is checked:

```
expect(page.isEnabledClaimedCheckbox).toBe("checked");
```

hasState is defined in POM file:

```
this.claimedCheckbox = browser.element(by.css('input[class="includeUnclaimedChk"]'));

this.isEnabledClaimedCheckbox= function() {
    return this.claimedCheckbox.getAttribute('checked');
};
```

Comment: element(by.css('.includeUnclaimedChk'));  AND element(by.css('input.includeUnclaimedChk'));

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attribute is not present then null will be returned by getAttribute().
[getAttribute() desc...](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute)

You can use the matcher - `expect(page.isEnabledClaimedCheckbox).toBeNull()`.